# Angular Routing Should Fail if No Child Route Is Matched

Tags: angular, angular-router

My real world example uses `loadChildren`, but I was able to reproduce the issue with regular children routes. Repro is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bsypzq?file=src/app/app.module.ts

If I have routes like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HelloComponent1
  },
  {
    path: "update",
    children: [
      {
        path: "reset",
        component: HelloComponent2
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Is it possible to configure the router so that attempting to go to `/update` will fail to match a url, just like it would if I were to attempt `/updatefake` or `/update/fake`? I know that I can add my own empty path child route (in the `children` array), and do something with it such as a redirect. However, I'm hoping to not have to mix that concern with child feature modules, and I'd rather it just show up as an invalid url match if someone tries going to just `/update`. If they go to `/update/reset`, then that should work.

Comment: There isn't any way that I know of specifically in the urlTree itself. If it is a separation of concerns issue, perhaps a route guard that disallows navigating to the root of that url could work?

Answer (score 0):

Make `”update/reset”` and any other `”update/“` prefixed routes siblings of `””` until there’s a reason to introduce hierarchical routing under `”update”`.

Comment: What qualifies as a “reason to introduce hierarchical routing”?

Comment: In the real world example, are you leveraging any other portion of the Route interface on the `”update”` parent to apply it to children? E.g. resolving data, guarding, etc.